# Geometry datatype to latitude /Longitude MS SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, geography

I need to convert Sql Server geometry datatype to latitude /Longitude

I have just imported a shapefile to my table (geometry)

This query does not work:-

```
select 
   geom.Lat as [Latitude],
   geom.Long as [Longitude]
from dbo.special
```

Error I get is:

> Could not find property or field 'Lat' for type 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeometry' in assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Types'.

This query returns Latitude and longitude but the format doesnot seem to match google maps:-

```
select U.name, Centroid.STY as Longitude, Centroid.STX as Latidude
 from
 ( select geom.STCentroid() as Centroid, NAME from dbo.special)
```

Also:-

```
SELECT ST_X (ST_Transform (geom, 4326)),
   ST_Y (ST_Transform (geom, 4326)) 
   FROM special
```

gives

> 'ST_Transform' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Please suggest

Comment: You have several questions here.  Please choose the most important one and efit the question to ask only that. You can ask the other questions in separate Questions.

Comment: Hi, I need to convert a geometry datatype to Latitude\Longitude. And then I have mentions a few ways i tried but failed. Like the first query gives an error which i dont understand. Could you please tell me what i am doing wrong

Answer (score 3):

This work for me:

```
  select 
   [GEOM].[STY] as [Latitude],
   [GEOM].[STX] as [Longitude]
   FROM [dbo].[SPECIAL]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using brackets around `Lat` and `Long`:

```
select 
[geom].[Lat] as [Latitude],
[geom].[Long] as [Longitude]
from dbo.special
```

Comment: This did not work. Could not find property or field 'Lat' for type 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeometry' in assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Types'.